# cURL command doesn't give JSON output but HTML page in Mac terminal

Tags: macos, curl, terminal, command-line

I'm doing some reqbin tutorials to learn about cURL commands. The simplest example given is:

```
curl -X POST https://reqbin.com/echo/post/json \
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
     -d '{"name":"Leo","age":26}' \
```

When I run this in their [on-line cURL editor](https://reqbin.com/curl), I get the correct JSON response:

```
{
    "success": "true"
}
```

When I paste this in my Mac terminal screen, I get a HTML response:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <title>Just a moment...</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta h
    ...
        }
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);
    }());
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

My cURL version was one that came with Mac:

```
curl --version

curl 7.88.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.0) libcurl/7.88.1 (SecureTransport) LibreSSL/3.3.6 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.51.0
Release-Date: 2023-02-20
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL threadsafe UnixSockets
```

I've update cURL with brew:

```
brew update
brew upgrade curl
```

Be careful, this takes forever...

I changed the symlink after that so that it points to my brew cURL instead of my Mac brew:

```
echo 'export PATH="$(brew --prefix)/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
source ~/.zshrc

-bash: ommand not found
-bash: 31mWarning: command not found
-bash: 00m: command not found
-bash: ommand not found
-bash: 31mPlease: command not found
-bash: 00m: command not found
-bash: ommand not found
-bash: 31m: command not found
-bash: 00m: command not found
```

Then checked the version again:

```
curl --version

$ curl 8.2.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin22.4.0) libcurl/8.2.0 (SecureTransport) OpenSSL/3.1.1 zlib/1.2.11 brotli/1.0.9 zstd/1.5.5 libidn2/2.3.4 libssh2/1.11.0 nghttp2/1.55.1 librtmp/2.3 OpenLDAP/2.6.5
Release-Date: 2023-07-19
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher gophers http https imap imaps ldap ldaps mqtt pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: alt-svc AsynchDNS brotli GSS-API HSTS HTTP2 HTTPS-proxy IDN IPv6 Kerberos Largefile libz MultiSSL NTLM NTLM_WB SPNEGO SSL threadsafe TLS-SRP UnixSockets zstd
```

But again, same HTML response. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CURL but rather the remote server, for whatever reason the server you're requesting JSON data from is not responding as you expect. 
Edit: Confirmed the remote server is misbehaving and doesn't return JSON data using the provided curl examples even under Linux, appears to be CloudFlare anti-bot interfering.